# Angular rewrites url for external font in scss

Tags: angular, sass, fonts

We use a Angular app along with the [IBM Plex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ibm/plex) font.

According to the developers of the font, the following configuration must be set in order to correctly load all fonts, which worked fine for Angular 9.

```scss
$font-prefix: "../node_modules/@ibm/plex";
@import "@ibm/plex/scss/ibm-plex";
```

Recently, we upgraded to Angular 10, and now the same configuration leads to the following error:

```
/path/to/project/node_modules/@ibm/plex/scss/mono/bold/_cyrillic.scss:5:2: 
Can't resolve '../node_modules/@ibm/plex/scss/mono/node_modules/@ibm/plex/IBM-Plex-Mono/fonts/split/woff2/IBMPlexMono-Bold-Cyrillic.woff2' 
in '/path/to/project/src'
```

It seems that the path which can't be found consists of three parts:

- `../node_modules/@ibm/plex/scss/mono/bold/` <-- I don't know where this comes from
- `../node_modules/@ibm/plex` <-- this is the value of `$font-prefix`
- `IBM-Plex-Mono/fonts/split/woff2/IBMPlexMono-Bold-Cyrillic.woff2` <-- this is the remaining path to the font file.

I have dug around in the code and the font library uses the following scss to import the font:

```scss
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('IBM Plex Sans'),
    local('IBMPlexSans'),
    url('#{$font-prefix}/IBM-Plex-Sans/fonts/split/woff2/IBMPlexSans-Regular-Latin1.woff2') format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000, U+000D, U+0020-007E, U+00A0-00A3, U+00A4-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2013-2014, U+2018-201A, U+201C-201E, U+2020-2022, U+2026, U+2030, U+2039-203A, U+2044, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2212, U+FB01-FB02;
}
```

I checked with a scss `@debug` statement that the variable `$font-prefix` actually contains the correct value (`../node_modules/@ibm/plex`), but it seems that somehow, the path which is passed to the `url` function is prefixed further (the first part of the above list). The font library did not change, so I assume it has to do something with the way that angular handles scss files? I would very much welcome a hint in which direction I can investigate further

Comment: Try to empty that $font-prefix var and see if that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it by prepending the variable like so:

```scss
$font-prefix: '~@ibm/plex';
```

Unfortunately, I could not find any documentation regarding this bug, and I don't know why this fixes the issue.